# How to get SPECIFIC elements from a mysql database as Json

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, database

I am trying to get All the list of names and surnames from a mysql database but only for a certain username and password by which an user is accessing the service.
I tried with the code below but it seems that is not working. Actually the JSONArray i get back is EMPTY.
Here my java code and Php code (which is on the server).
The whole code is working great if I don't filter by username and password so actually i receive back the list. But as I try to filter by username and password the JsonArray is Null.
Please I will appreciate any clue!

```
    public class ApiConnector {  
    public JSONArray GetAllCustomers(User user){
    String url = "http://giacomoci.co.uk/FetchallDataList.php";

    ArrayList<NameValuePair> dataToSend = new ArrayList<>();
    dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", user.username));
    dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", user.password));


    HttpParams httpRequestParams = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpRequestParams, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpRequestParams, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);

    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpRequestParams);
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);

    JSONArray jsonArray = null;

    try {


        //DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        //HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(dataToSend));


        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(post);

        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

        if(httpEntity != null){

            try {

                String entityResponse = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
                Log.e("Entity Response : ", entityResponse);

                jsonArray = new JSONArray(entityResponse);
            }catch (JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return jsonArray;
}
    }
```

And here my PHP code

```
$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];


$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT name, surname FROM Contacts WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ss", $username, $password);

$user[] = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($statement)){

    $user[] = $row;

}


echo json_encode($user);

mysqli_close($con);
```

So if I delete "Where username = ? AND password = ?" and the following line everything goes fine, but I get names and surnames for all the usernames and passwords, as I don't want. What's wrong with this code?

Comment: You really should use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: Visiting the URL alone produces a JSON string so if passing POST values to it is producing no JSON string then you should try running your SQL directly against the MySQL database with MySQL Workbench.

Comment: If the password is encoded (and it really should be), your simple script won't find the record you are looking for. Check the data you have in the database. If the password is encoded you need to find what kind of encoding it has and figure out how to apply the same encoding in your php code to compare the password value.

Comment: Thanks for replying guys, actually I am not applying any encoding to the password since I want firs test all the basic services of my app but I am aware that I will  need to perform some encoding for security reasons. So the password I'm using is just a String. I'm using the same password to perform other filtering on the server and it actually works good. Then I just tested the service using only the "username" on the server to select certain name and surname but is still not working! So it seems that it doesn't really depends on the "password" I am passing

Answer (score 0):

```
$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
```

Replace those `_POST` with `_GET`

```
$username = $_GET["username"];
$password = $_GET["password"];
```

Comment: Thanks for your clue! I just tested it but unfortunately the result is the same. the Json I get back is Empty, so the filter has no effect

Comment: Usually what I try for debugging purposes are the following steps (note that I'm quite new to android aswell, so these may not be the most elegant solutions):

1. Check if it works in your database, so execute the (select) statement in your MySQL program and see if it returns anything there at all.

2. Check if the PHP script returns anything in your browser, so put the .php script on your server and access it from your browser (by typing the URL). Make sure to echo the result (which would be this in your case: echo json_encode($user);) and see if that works.

3. Log in android using Log.d();

Comment: Only go to the next step if the previous step works of course. 
The point is to find out exactly in which part of the system the problem lies. It's good practice to always start with a minimal test method, like select one username and show it in a label as text. As long as that works, you can continue to update it to suit your needs. Like a 'hello-world'-like debugging.